# Firebase transfer to new firebaseio link

Tags: firebase

Does anyone know if it is easy to transfer data between two firebase apps? I would like to explore the possibility of having to change the xxx.firebaseio.com link that my app is using after the launch, and would like to know if it is possible to transfer the data and user's login credentials from one firebase.io link to a new firebaseio.com link.

Thanks for any comments on this.

Abhishek

Comment: Data is easy, via admin tool, you may just export/import in JSON. For credentials, you can maybe create new users (user not in the new DB) in the new DB, when they succeed log in the old DB. Has to be checked

Comment: Depending on the data this may not work because creating a new user in the second db will also create a new uuid for that user. If you have the data coupled to the uuid in the original db you will have troubles coupling that data to the newly generated uuid.

Comment: Thanks Andre and Anthony. I use uuid throughout my rules, so it seems transferring data by export/import of JSON objects may not work for me. I will reach out to customer support to find a solution for transferring accounts by maintaining the uuid.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the Firebase CLI to transfer data between Firebase databases.**

```
firebase data:get / -f my-firebase-db | firebase data:set / -f another-firebase -y
```

Or you can use [`firebase-dot-files`](https://github.com/davideast/firebase-dot-files), that has a bash function called `transfer_to`.

```
transfer_to dev-firebase staging-firebase
```

As far as transferring accounts goes, that is not a common scenario so you may need to contact support@firebase.com to see what is possible.